# How can I take a UNION of two separate sql queries and get only DISTINCT values

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I get only the distinct values out of these two queries of mine in PHP:

```
$query1 = "SELECT g.name, g.hash, g.views
                    FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga
                    WHERE g.category >= 592 AND g.category <= 622
                        AND ga.affiliated_groups_hash = g.hash
                        AND LOWER(g.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')
                        ";
        $query2 = "SELECT g.name, g.hash, g.views
                    FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga, c7_affiliations a
                    WHERE ga.affiliations_id = a.id
                        AND ga.groups_hash = g.hash
                        AND LOWER(a.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')";
```

I want to get only the distinct "g.hash" from both these queries. Its even better if i could have one sql query that would do both the tasks.

The details about my database table are as:
c7_groups:
id  int(10)
name    varchar(255)
hash    varchar(32)
groups_categories_id    int(10)
views   int(10)

c7_affiliations
id  int(10) 
name    varchar(100)
groups_categories_id    int(10)

c7_groups_affiliations
groups_hash varchar(32)                             affiliated_groups_hash  varchar(32)--------FKey to c7_groups.hash
affiliations_id int(10)--------------------FKey to c7_affiliations.id
id    int(10)

both affiliated_groups_hash & affiliations_id could be null, or i should say one or them would always be null. If a groups is affiliated to another group, affiliations_id will be null and if the group is affiliated to to another affiliation, affiliated_groups_hash will be null.

Let me know if you need any more details about anything.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Distinct 
           g.name, g.hash, g.views
                    FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga
                    WHERE g.category >= 592 AND g.category <= 622
                        AND ga.affiliated_groups_hash = g.hash
                        AND LOWER(g.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')
UNION
SELECT 
           g.name, g.hash, g.views
                    FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga, c7_affiliations a
                    WHERE ga.affiliations_id = a.id
                        AND ga.groups_hash = g.hash
                        AND LOWER(a.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')
```

Comment: I formatted your code for you. All that I did was highlight the statement and press the {} button

Answer (score 2):

Just do the union in a sub-select, then group by the derived table.

```
select name,count(*) from
(
               SELECT g.name, g.hash, g.views
                    FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga
                    WHERE g.category >= 592 AND g.category <= 622
                        AND ga.affiliated_groups_hash = g.hash
                        AND LOWER(g.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')
     UNION
               SELECT g.name, g.hash, g.views
                    FROM c7_groups g, c7_groups_affiliations ga, c7_affiliations a
                    WHERE ga.affiliations_id = a.id
                        AND ga.groups_hash = g.hash
                        AND LOWER(a.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')";
) as myTbl
group by name
```

Comment: You can also use `distinct` instead of an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only difference between the first query and the second is there's a join. Perhaps if you used ANSI-92 joins it would have been like this and there would be no need for UNION.

```
          SELECT DISTINCT 
                   g.name, 
                   g.hash,
                   g.views
            FROM 
                    c7_groups g
                  INNER JOIN  c7_groups_affiliations ga
                  ON ga.affiliated_groups_hash = g.hash
                  LEFT JOIN c7_affiliations a
                   on ga.affiliations_id = a.id

            WHERE 
                (LOWER(g.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')
                 AND g.category >= 592 AND g.category <= 622 
                 AND  a.ID is null)
                OR 
                 (LOWER(a.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')
                 and a.ID is NOT null)
```

Technically the `a.ID is NOT null` in the second part isn't required since `LOWER(a.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')` does this but it makes it a little clearer what's happening

Comment: No you missed one criteria. if the group has an affiliation with another affiliation, then the criteria to check has to be : "LOWER(a.name) LIKE LOWER('%$school_name%')"

Comment: @Zeeshan Rang. Thanks. It oddly enough makes it a little clearer